# selector jquery after item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I select just `210.00` with a selector?

```
<tr class="order-total">
  <th>Total</th>
  <td data-title="Total">
    <strong>
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>
        210.00
      </span>
    </strong> 
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I think you should put this value 210.00 in an element (span for example. Then, it'll be much easier to select it :)

Comment: `$('.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount:contains(210.00)')`......is it?

Comment: You need to put `210.00` in `<span>` for example, after you get `span` element and you can use `.text()`

Comment: the probleme is 210 not static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try

```
var allChildNodes = $("td[data-title='Total'] span").first()[0].childNodes;
var lastSpanNode = allChildNodes[ allChildNodes.length - 1 ];
```

or

```
var allChildNodes = $("td[data-title='Total']").find("span").first()[0].childNodes;
var lastSpanNode = allChildNodes[ allChildNodes.length - 1 ];
```

get its value by doing

```
lastSpanNode.nodeValue
```

Comment: it return [text object ]

Comment: @YaSsineTagmatRakini you need to get value by doing `lastSpanNode.nodeValue`

Comment: thanks  for your helping  . can you help me could you tell me how can i update its text (210.00)

Comment: you can also change the node value

Comment: how can i change its text

Comment: Changing nodevalue will change the text

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var myNumber = $('.woocommerce-Price-amount').html().replace("<span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">$</span>", "");
alert(myNumber.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Another small way to find out `210.00`

```
var total = $('tr.order-total td[data-title="Total"]').text().replace('$', '').trim();
console.log(total);
```

Woring URL: https://jsfiddle.net/mb7s24pb/